# How to add all MonoBehaviours of Scene into the List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've read an article [10000 UPDATE() CALLS](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/).
Author uses UpdateManager. It has `Update` method which calls `Update` method in all of other MonoBehaviours of objects. It works faster than calling `Update` method from each MonoBehaviour separately.

This Manager looks like:

```
private ManagedUpdateBehavior[] list;

private void Start() {
    list = GetComponents<ManagedUpdateBehavior>();
}

private void Update() {
    var count = list.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // UpdateMe
        list[i].UpdateMe();
    }
}
```

And every objects now contains component with the code:

```
public class ManagedUpdateBehavior : MonoBehaviour {
    // some variables

    public void UpdateMe() {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

It's okay if 5-6-7-8- objects will be have that component.

But what if I have 100 objects? 1000? 10000?

How to find and add all `ManagedUpdateBehaviors` from all objects of scene? Should I use some recursive method on `On Start`? Cause every object may contain other objects with the script, they may contain the other objects etc...unlimited nesting

Also some objects can be instantiating dynamically...How to add their mono to manager? What is the right way?

Comment: You can make a static list of managed monobehaviours, and on the `Start()` function of each monobehaviour add it to that list, then read from that list in the manager.

Comment: @YotamSalmon Neee. I don't think it's a good idea.  What if I have 50..100 Monobehaviours? Manually add code to each script? What if I change my mind? Remove manually? Change my mind again?)) It is not productively.......`java 8` has interfaces which can contain default methods (with realization)... It would be nice if C# has something like that....That would be more right, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also some objects can be instantiating dynamically

Let each `ManagedUpdateBehavior` subscribe to the `ManagedUpdateBehavior` list by adding its instance to the `ManagedUpdateBehavior` instance. They should also unsubscribe from the `ManagedUpdateBehavior` when destroyed by removing itself from the `ManagedUpdateBehavior` instance.

Your new `ManagedUpdateBehavior` script:

```
public class ManagedUpdateBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    UpdateSubscriber updateSUBSCR;

    //Add it self to the List
    void Start()
    {
        updateSUBSCR = GameObject.Find("UpdateSUBSCR").GetComponent<UpdateSubscriber>();
        updateSUBSCR.addManagedUpdateBehavior(this);
    }

    //Remove it self from the List
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        updateSUBSCR.removeManagedUpdateBehavior(this);
    }

    public void UpdateMe()
    {
        // some logic
        Debug.Log("Update from: " + gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Create a GameObject called **UpdateSUBSCR** and attach the Script below to it:

```
public class UpdateSubscriber : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<ManagedUpdateBehavior> managedUpdateBehavior = new List<ManagedUpdateBehavior>();


    public void addManagedUpdateBehavior(ManagedUpdateBehavior managedUB)
    {
        managedUpdateBehavior.Add(managedUB);
    }

    public void removeManagedUpdateBehavior(ManagedUpdateBehavior managedUB)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < managedUpdateBehavior.Count; i++)
        {
            if (managedUpdateBehavior[i] == managedUB)
            {
                managedUpdateBehavior.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    public List<ManagedUpdateBehavior> getManagedUpdateBehaviorinstance
    {
        get
        {
            return managedUpdateBehavior;
        }
    }*/

    public void updateAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < managedUpdateBehavior.Count; i++)
        {
            managedUpdateBehavior[i].UpdateMe();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    UpdateSubscriber updateSUBSCR;

    void Start()
    {
        updateSUBSCR = GameObject.Find("UpdateSUBSCR").GetComponent<UpdateSubscriber>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        updateSUBSCR.callUpdateFuncs();
    }
}
```

Be aware that array is faster than `List` but this is better than the having the `Update()` function in every script.

Comment: So, there is no more right way to do that, than add manually this code to each Monobehaviour? :'(   I mean,  What if I have 50..100 Monobehaviours and I change my mind? Remove that code (from `Start`, `OnDestroy` and `UpdateSubscriber updateSUBSCR;`) manually from everywhere? 
There is no something more universal method to add this logic to objects? For example: to use some global script that watch if something has been instantiated on  scene and add its mono to list.
Or something like `Java`'s 8 interfaces with default logic.... Or this is the only way? Hard but right :)

Comment: @AlexeyShimansky I don't really understand what you are saying. You are **NOT** doing anything manually. Every GameObject will automatically add it self when instantiated and remove itself when destroyed. All you have to do is attach `ManagedUpdateBehavior` to each GameObject or your prefabs. Create one GameObject called UpdateSUBSCR and attach `UpdateSUBSCR` script to it.

Comment: Now, to actually call the `Update` functions, you have to put the code in the `Test` script above to your main game code. You Main game code will then automatically call all the Update functions from other scripts by just calling `updateSUBSCR.callUpdateFuncs();`

Comment: I did that to give you more control. You can also add `void Update()
    {
        updateSUBSCR.callUpdateFuncs();
    }` code to the `UpdateSubscriber` script then you will never have to do it from your main script. Please explain to me where think you are doing anything manually.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very slow today)) I forgot ( And I don't really know how ) that I can just attach `ManagedUpdateBehavior` to all objects...I thought (bacause my stupid brain) that I should add these lines: `UpdateSubscriber updateSUBSCR;`, `updateSUBSCR = GameObject.Find("UpdateSUBSCR").GetComponent<UpdateSubscriber>();
        updateSUBSCR.addManagedUpdateBehavior(this);` and `updateSUBSCR.removeManagedUpdateBehavior(this);` to all my other scripts (PlayerScript, EnemyScript, ControllersScript, FxScripts and a lot more scripts ))) ..this I meant when said about manually... Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @AlexeyShimansky Noo you don't have to. I am glad you get it now. If you have any more questions while setting it up, you feel free to ask for more question. I tested that and it works as expected. Happy coding!

Comment: Well, I have just one. Instead of attach script to every object - I think about to create `abstract` class named as `BaseClass` which will be inherited from the `MonoBehaviour`....
It will be contain all code from `ManagedUpdateBehavior`, but `UpdateMe` will be `abstract`. http://pastebin.com/QCiKZ09P ..Then every main class will be inherited from `BaseClass`, e.g. `class BaseEnemy : BaseClass {` 
or  `class BasePlayer : BaseClass {` etc. Will it be wrong? Children will be inherited from Its parent. I don't see any problem with inheritance in future. But I'm not sure

Comment: @AlexeyShimansky This actually make sense to me.  Please give it a try and let know if that works. I've not tried that but let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can find and add all ManagedUpdateBehaviours using [Object.FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) method.

You can add your dynamically instantiate objects using a static method that can be called from created game object to add it to list.

My suggestion is created a SceneUpdateManager, something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class SceneUpdateManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static List<ManagedUpdateBehavior> list;

    private void Start () 
    {
        list = Object.FindObjectsOfType<ManagedUpdateBehavior> ().ToList ();
    }

    public static void AddBehavior(ManagedUpdateBehavior behaviour)
    {
        list.Add (behaviour);
    }

    private void Update () {
        var count = list.Count;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list [i].UpdateMe();
        }
    }
}
```

> Object.FindObjectsOfType does not return inactive objects.